# create library of custom element html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-tag

I'm trying to create a custom element HTML5, I extend input tag

you can see my code here :

```
<form id="form">
login : <input type='text' id='login' class='form-control'/>
password :   <nc-input id='pass'/>
name : <input type='text' id='name' class='form-control'/>
</form>

<script>
//declare a function that create tag
function createTag(tagName,HTMLElementType,HTMLName,HTMLType)
{

var proto = Object.create(HTMLElementType.prototype);
proto.createdCallback = function() {
    this.type = HTMLType;
    this.className = 'form-control'
};

//var host = document.querySelector("#form");
//var shadow = host.createShadowRoot();

var nCB = document.registerElement(tagName, {
    prototype: proto,
    extends: HTMLName
});

document.body.appendChild(new nCB());  //JS DOM

}

createTag('nc-input',HTMLInputElement,'input','text');
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NABILDEV/5z44v30x/22/

using this line : `document.body.appendChild(new nCB());`

it displays the input on the bottom of the page and not inside my form (next to password label).

my purpose is to create my own tag's library, so I can use them in my project

Thanks.

Comment: don't append to the dom in a `createdCallback`, "append" it by creating the element, hard-coded in HTML. in short, kill the last line. that said, you can't extent inputs like that, you would need to use `<input is=nc-input>` to have the control inherit from your definition and the normal input API (where supported).

Comment: Replace `document.body.appendChild(new nCB());` with `document.getElementById('form').appendChild(new nCB());` This will append the elements to the form rather than the page body.

Comment: @NewToJS: no, there's no need to append it anywhere, it's defined via markup.

Comment: Ah wait, scrap that, it won't appear next to the password label anyway, it will append it to the bottom of the form.

Comment: it doesn't need instantiated, just calling `document.registerElement` will make it work in-place...

Comment: @dandavis I want use tag like <nc-input>..... if I don't use append I can't see my tag anymore in the form....@newtojs if I replace body by form the tag is place in the bottom of the form

Comment: i think you're wanting this: http://jsfiddle.net/9pdhz901/ (look at the classname on the the middle input)

Comment: or maybe something more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qL6zLgxp/ (i don't know why all the jquery errors appear, but jq is not needed anyway...

Comment: @dandavis great it's working fine...just one last question how can I do to use <nc-input />  instead of <nc-input></nc-input> is there any property missing ?

Comment: @user3347018: you can't; you need to have an explicit close tag for all custom elements. just adding "/>" to the open tag does NOT make it self-closing. only a few pre-approved tags can be self-closing, and there's no way (currently) to add your element onto that list. sorry.